# Add image style after drop event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 5 pieces of a image in a container which i have to drop in another container to complete the image. After the image is dropped in another container i want to add style="position:absolute" to that image so that this image piece will stick to the previous image present in this container.

I am able to implement the drag and drop event but unable to add css style after drop  event. Here is JSFiddle link so that you can help me http://jsfiddle.net/binit/JnYB9/

```
<script>
$(function() {

$( "#sortable1" ).sortable({
connectWith: "div"
});

$( "#sortable2" ).sortable({
connectWith: "div"

});

$( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).disableSelection();
});
</script>
<body>   
<div class="row-fluid" >
<div class="span4">
    <div class="span1"></div>
    <div id="sortable1" class="well sidebar-nav sidebar-nav-fixed span11">
        <legend>Collect Coupon parts</legend>
        1st part
        <img class="ui-state-highlight" src="{% static 'images/demo/north.png' %}" >
        2nd part
        <img class="ui-state-highlight" src="{% static 'images/demo/south.png' %}" >
        3rd part
        <img class="ui-state-highlight" src="{% static 'images/demo/east.png' %}" >
        4th part
        <img class="ui-state-highlight" src="{% static 'images/demo/west.png' %}" >
        5th part
        <img class="ui-state-highlight" src="{% static 'images/demo/center.png' %}"  >
    </div>
</div>
<div id="sortable2" class=" well sidebar-nav sidebar-nav-fixed span8">

    <legend>Canvas section</legend>
 </div>
```

Comment: like so: http://jsfiddle.net/Zd2sn/ ? What for?

Comment: or more like in a jigsaw puzzle: http://jsfiddle.net/gkwkf/ ?

Answer (score 0):

try this, i just used call back receive: on sortable2 and apply css to img

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kFzR3/)

```
    $(function() {

$( "#sortable1" ).sortable({
connectWith: "div"
});

$( "#sortable2" ).sortable({
connectWith: "div",
    receive:  function(){
        $("#sortable2 img").css('position','absolute');
    }

});

$( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).disableSelection();
});
```